# c# extension method with linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to write an extension method to filter all the people with towns in a people object with the towns in shop object

```
class people
    string name
    string town

class shops
    string category
    string town
```

i know i can write

```
var x = from p in people
        from s in shops
        where p.town == s.town
```

but i would like to know how to write

```
var x = from p in people.FilterByTown(p) or FilterByTown(p => p.town) or however it is!!
```

where FilterByTown is the extension method and all the magic works in there and the object i pass in gets compared with the shop object.

It needs to work with different objects being fed to the method

Hope that all makes sense, the code above is obviously pseudo!

Comment: Why aren't your classes called Person and Shop, and shouldn't the people in "from p in people" be some kind of collection (IQueryable<Person> or IEnumerable<Person>)?

Comment: What exactly is `FilterByTown` supposed to do? The exact same thing as your query?

Comment: I guess that if you ask for that, maybe you haven't understood well how extension methods work.. You should take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and then you will be able to answer the question yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 2 collections people and shops you can write this:

```
List<People> people = ...
List<Shops> shops = ...

IEnumerable<People> Filter(this IEnumerable<People> people, IEnumerable<Shops> shops){
var result = people.Where(p=>shops.Any(s=>s.town == p.town));
return result;
}
```

If you want to sort all classes by some arbitrary property you can try this version:

```
public static IEnumerable<T1> Filter<T1, T2>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> one, 
    IEnumerable<T2> two, string property)
        {
           var result = one.Where(o => two.Any(t =>
               o.GetType().GetProperty(property).
               GetValue(o, null).Equals(t.GetType().
               GetProperty(property).GetValue(t, null))));
           return result;
        }
```

Of course you need to be sure that property is valid and both objects have it.

Comment: What id i had several objects which had the twon in other than people. I would then have to pass various types in, through T? how would i access their properties without knowing the type

Comment: Are you saying you want to compare entities(e.g. people and shops) by arbitrary properties?

Comment: This is the answer i was after, thanks to all contributions especially blablablaster

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection, you can filter based on any property of any type:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FilterByProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                                 string property,
                                                 object value)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);

    return source.Where(p => propertyInfo.GetValue(p, null) == value);
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<People> cityPeople = myPeople.FilterByTown("Town", "MyCity");
```

And if you want a list:

```
List<People> cityPeopleList = myPeople.FilterByTown("MyCity").ToList();
```

Comment: The above will not work as i want the method to take other objects which may also have a town property, so i was expecting a type T to be in the method signature but when you do that you lose the type so cannot pick up the town property

Comment: @MarkLawson I think I understand you much better now. See my edit.

Comment: Nearly there, we have passed in a list of people, but inside the method we need to compare that list with a list of shops and find the matching towns

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<People> FilterByTown(this IEnumerable<People> people, IList<Shop> shops)
{
    return people.Where(p => shops.Any(s => s.Town == p.Town));
}
```

Usage:

```
peoples.FilterByTown(shops);
```

Comment: This is much closer but i want the method to take other objects which may also have a town property, so i was expecting a type T to be in the method signature but when you do that you lose the type so cannot pick up the town property

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up the queries if you create a list of unique towns

```
public static class PeopleExtensions
{                             
    private static List<string> _distinctShopTowns;

    private static List<Shop> _shops;
    public static List<Shop> Shops
    {
        get { return _shops; }
        set {
            _shops = value;
            _distinctShopTowns = _shops
                .Select(shop => shop.town)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();
        } 
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Person> PeopleInTownsWithShops(this IEnumerable<Person> people)
    {
        return people.Where(p => _distinctShopTowns.Contains(p.town));
    }
}
```

You can call it like this

```
List<Shop> shops = ...;
List<Person> people = ...;

PeopleExtensions.Shops = shops; // Do every time the shop list changes.

var x = from p in people.PeopleInTownsWithShops();
```